# Flutter google_maps pinch to zoom

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to implement a google_maps in flutter where I can zoom-in and zoom-out by pinching like official google maps. I cannot find any method for implementing the same.
My code snippet is -

```
GoogleMap(
       onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
       initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: _center,
       zoom: -3.0
       ),
       scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
       zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
       myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
       gestureRecognizers: Set()
         ..add( Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
       markers: markers
   );
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you try to set the zoom level tot a value > 0. I think the zoom level is between 0 and 24 there's no negative values for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the zoom level is negative however the min zoom level is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is also correct but if your map is wrapped in the SingleChildScrollView() widget then the zoom feature will not work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Just upgrade the flutter SDK,
And now its working.